# Django: Display count of child in HTML template when querying Parent

Tags: python, django, orm

I have to objects named `Service` with a child `Requirements`.
What im trying to achieve is, First Filtering the `service` object and and displaying it and below of it display count of requirements. something like in below image. which shows the Service and count of Requirement associated to the Services, and also displaying Total count of requirements with status = 'Verified'

[image]

Models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Requirements(models.Model):
    Requirements= models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    file= models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    services= models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Views.py

```
def test_one(request):
    comp_id = request.session['comp_id']
    service = service.objects.filter(company_id=comp_id)

    for services in service:
        list = services.req_document_set.all()

    print(service )
    for i in service :

        total_checklist = len(Requirements.objects.filter(services_id=i.id))    
        total_verified = len(Requirements.objects.filter(services_id=i.id, reqdoc_status='Verified'))    


        print(total_checklist)
        print(total_verified)


    context = {'service ': service , 'total_checklist': total_checklist, 'total_verified ': total_verified }

    return render(request, 'test1.html', context)
```

test1.html

```
<table>
{% for services in service %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{services.services}}
        <ul>
          <li>Total Requirements Count = {{total_checklist}}</li>
          <li>Total Verified Count = {{total_verified }}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
  </table>
```

on the terminal, i was able to print a loop of the count
3
1
0
0
which means i have 2 Services, in 1st service i have 3 total req and 1 total req verified and on the 2nd service i have 0 total req and 0 total verified requirements. but i dont know how to display this on the HTML template. when using the above template it only display the very last looped data which is the 2nd Service. 
Hope Someone how can i do this. not very familiar with ORM's yet.

Comment: What is `req_info` in your `views.py`?

Comment: @PedramParsian Oops. sorry its supposed to be service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your models and what you want to achieve:

**template**

```
<table>
  {% for service in services %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ service.services }}
        <ul>
          <li>Total Requirements Count = {{ service.requirements_set.count }}</li>
          <li>Total Verified Count = {{ service.get_verifed_req_count }}</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_verifed_req_count(self):
        return self.requirements_set.filter(reqdoc_status='Verified').count()


class Requirements(models.Model):
    Requirements = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    file = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    services = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=254)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def test_one(request):
    comp_id = request.session['comp_id']
    service = service.objects.filter(company_id=comp_id)
    context = {'services': service}
    return render(request, 'test1.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks dude. really work for me, didn't really know this kind of function until now. 
`def get_verifed_req_count(self):
        return self.requirements_set.filter(reqdoc_status='Verified').count()

`